# Disabling the form field on submit

Tags: webforms

I have a webform where I've used form alter to do some functionality and validation.

Now in my validation I want to disable a field for a purpose. How can I do so? Is it possible in form validation?

Answer (score 0):

I think what are looking for is [hook_node_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7)

> Perform node validation before a node is created or updated.
>
> This hook is invoked from node_validate(), after a user has has
>   finished editing the node and is previewing or submitting it. It is
>   invoked at the end of all the standard validation steps, and after the
>   type-specific hook_validate() is invoked.